# Merge 2 txt files with different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 datasets, both `.txt` files. Initialized as:

```
df_a = pd.read_csv("path_a.txt")
# df_a.shape = (50000, 8)
df_b = pd.read_csv("path_b.txt")
# df_b.shape = (8000, 8)
```

Their `8` columns has same names. I want to merge both by `col_1`, which is a timestamp column in unix format, and creating a dataset of shape `(50000, 15)`. As `df_b` has only 8000 rows, if I do the join, I'm getting a dataset of shape `(8000, 15)`.

I want to add `0` values to the rest of the `42000` rows left of `df_b` so that the shape of te final output is `(50000, 15)`, how can I do that?

**EDIT. ADDING EXAMPLE OF THE ROWS**

```
# df_a (no index nor header)
...
1603107058, 1, 1.10, 17.27, 220.1, 22.51, 8.98, 9.21
1603107059, 1, 85.0, 87.147, 30.5, 21.01, 5.44, 7.665
1603107060, 0, 86.0, 30.1692, 30.1764, 30.1400, 30.1459, 687.674
1603107061, 2, 87.0, 34.12, 10.24, 32.2410, 31.115, 7.57
...

# df_a (no index nor header)
# first value of the 8.000 rows. As you can see, in df_a are more values before this unix timestamp
1603107060, 0, 67.1, 1854.2, 22.0, 144.4, 10.3, 80.1
1603107061, 4, 11.0, 2.12, 12.1, 12.4440, 42.213, 57.17
...

# colA ==> unix timestamp (1603107060, ..., and so on)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
...
1603107058, 1, 1.10, 17.27, 220.1, 22.51, 8.98, 9.21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1603107059, 1, 85.0, 87.147, 30.5, 21.01, 5.44, 7.665, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1603107060, 0, 86.0, 30.1692, 30.1764, 30.1400, 30.1459, 687.674, 0, 67.1, 1854.2, 22.0, 144.4, 10.3, 80.1
1603107061, 2, 87.0, 34.12, 10.24, 32.2410, 31.115, 7.57, 4, 11.0, 2.12, 12.1, 12.4440, 42.213, 57.17
...
```

PD: my shape has 15 columns because `df_a` has 8 cols and `df_b` has another 8 cols, but I do the join by one in common of them, so that makes `7 + 7 + 1`, being 1 the joining column used.

Comment: Will you please add a few rows from the two csv files to the question? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @user17242583 sure! i've added it

Comment: Okay, nice. Please add sample dataframe based off of those rows, that contains the output you're looking to get.

Comment: @user17242583 done. sorry for not adding that before!

Comment: how are you doing the join? by default pandas does a left join so if you want to keep all 50,000 rows from df_a you would need to df_a.join(df_b) https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN should be the way, but more specifically, an outer JOIN.

To make it simpler, you may need to assign some distinct names, and suppose the shared key is `ts`:

```
df_a = pd.read_csv("a.txt", names=['ts', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
# df_a.shape = (50000, 8)
df_b = pd.read_csv("b.txt", names=['ts', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'])
# df_b.shape = (8000, 8)
```

Then you'd want to perform a typical outer join on the `ts` key, and finally chained with a `.fillna` method to displace the null values as 0:

```
df = df_a.join(df_b.set_index('ts'), on='ts').fillna(0)
```

Which should get you the result as:

[image: joined]